# The given path's format is not supported, Windows Store

Tags: c#, cryptography, windows-store-apps, aes

I'm trying to encrypt a file in a Windows 8.1 Store application, using an AES library [found here](https://www.aescrypt.com/sharp_aes_crypt.html). However, when I try to encrypt the file, I get a System.NotSupportedException.
I have tried entering the file path directly as a string, this gave the same error. When I look at the file path string (called savePath), it reads C:\Users\MyName\TheLibrary\TestDocument.doc
Here's my code:

```
private async void EncryptFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filePathTextBox.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(SaveLocationTextBox.Text))
            {
                MessageDialog msgDialog = new MessageDialog("Please select a file AND a save location", "");
                await msgDialog.ShowAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                string format = "C:\\Users\\MyName\\";
                string fileName = fileNameTextBox.Text;
                string savePath = Path.Combine(format, folderPathTextBox.Text, fileName);
                //encryption
                SharpAESCrypt.SharpAESCrypt.Encrypt("password", filePathTextBox.Text, savePath);
                EncryptStatus.Text = "File Sucessfully Encrypted";
            }

        }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please post the full exception details (message and stack trace)

Comment: BTW, this library doesn't seem to be designed for WinRT... I see that the original code uses File.OpenRead and similar APIs, which are not available on WinRT. Did you modify yourself for e.g. file access? In WinRT you can't access a file at an arbitrary path.

Comment: Ah, that would be the issue, no I haven't modified it, I missed that when looking through the code.
Seeing as a file cannot be accessed at a particular path, it would make sense that the file path code wouldn't work. I will have to find another way of implementing this then.

Comment: I should mention that I am attempting to access the documents/photos/downloads/music folders, using a file picker